# jxbrowser progress listener is missing for v6.7

Tags: jxbrowser

Older jxbrowser has progress listener, http://site.staging.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc3/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/events/ProgressListener.html

Where is the equivalent progress listener for v6.7? How can I subscribe to progress for this version?

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser 6.7 doesn't have this API anymore, because it was removed from Chromium API in the latest Chromium builds.

Comment: Too bad, I guess I have to fake the progress when the page start to load.